# problem in getting error response through ajax requesting a url

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start=0&rows=10&q=ring&json.wrf=?",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain:'true',
    dataType:'json',
    complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus) {

                        alert(textStatus);

         }
    })
```

if url is correct i get `success` but if url is not correct suppose `ip` is wrong , than complete function does not execute. than how can i determine that url is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `error()`, This will handle all type of errors.

example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start=0&rows=10&q=ring&json.wrf=?",
   type: 'GET',
   crossDomain:'true',
   dataType:'json',
   complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus) {
       alert(textStatus);
   },
   error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert("Error : " + textStatus);
   } 
});
```

Comment: look at http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/69/ , in this i used two url one is correct (commented one) and one is incorect . in case of incorect it does not go in error() why so

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is just like success handling:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start=0&rows=10&q=ring&json.wrf=?",
   type: 'GET',
   crossDomain:'true',
   dataType:'json',
   complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus) {
       alert(textStatus);
   },
   success:function(data){
      // handle data object
   },
   error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert("Error : " + textStatus);
   } 
});
```

Talha has the right idea but his syntax is incorrect.

Comment: i have done exactly as you said but when connection is not proper than also it is not going into error. i experiment it as : i incorrected the url put slr in place of solr